# Remove-PSDrive does not remove drives

Tags: powershell

I use Powershell > 4 to create and remove drives on my computer. I connect them locally to a folder or to remote drives:

```
New-PSDrive -Name L -PSProvider FileSystem -Root ($userprofile + "\Documents\whatever") -Scope Global -Persist
New-PSDrive -Name I -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\server\whatever -Scope Global -Persist -Credential $usercred
```

Now I would like to change the drives and disconnect them via:

```
Get-PSDrive -Name L, I -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Remove-PSDrive -Scope Global -Force
```

Without `-ErrorAction` I get the following message for the network drives which are currently not reachable:

```
Get-PSDrive : The drive was not found. A drive with the name "I" does not exist.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ Get-PSDrive -Name L, I -Scope  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (I:String) [Get-PSDrive], DriveNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetDriveNoMatchingDrive,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetPSDriveCommand
```

Unfortunately, all drives (including L) are not removed or disconnected. I check this via `net use` and get:

```
Getrennt   I:   \\Server\whatever                    Microsoft Windows Network
OK         L:   \\localhost\C$\...\Documents\wrong   Microsoft Windows Network
```

Do you have an idea why `Remove-PSDrive` does not do its job?

Comment: `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` and you can't see why it's not working, you say? Do you get an error if you remove that?

Comment: I tried it and got an error. Don't ask me why I did not add it to my question. I edit the question.

Comment: Error in English: "The drive was not found. A drive with the name "I" does not exist."

Comment: Does it work with just the L drive ?

Comment: I get no error message for the L drive. However, it is still reachable.

Comment: I prefer to assign the drives to a variable at creation: `$PSDriveI = New-PSDrive -Name I -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\server\share` and `$PSDriveL = New-PSDrive -Name I -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\server\share` You can then remove them simply by piping the variable `$PSDriveI, $PSDriveL | Remove-PSDrive`

Comment: This is a possibility. But I use them with option `-Persist` and want to remove them after e.g. a restart. In this case, I have no variables.

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same problem with Remove-PSDrive not removing any network drives and not outputting any error either, so I fixed this problem by using a combination of powershell and the good old "net use"

```
$psdrive = psdrive | Where { $_.DisplayRoot -like '\\*' }
foreach ($mapdrive in $psdrive){

if($mapdrive.DisplayRoot -Like '\\NetworkPath\folder\etc*'){

$driveLetter = ($mapdrive.Root) -replace "\\",""
$drivePath = $mapdrive.DisplayRoot
Write-Host "Removing drive $driveLetter with path $drivePath" -foregroundcolor green

net use $driveLetter /delete

}
}
```

Comment: This is a possibility. However, I am astonished, that this does not work with PS itself.

Comment: A one-liner that uses _net use_ in a PowerShell command `Start-Process -FilePath "net" -ArgumentList "use $((Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_mappedLogicalDisk -filter "ProviderName='\\\\NetworkPath\\folder\\etc'").Name.SubString(0, 1)): /delete"`

Comment: Back here again a year later and again, shaking my head that I have to use `net use /delete` to remove a mapping created with `New-PSDrive`

Answer (score 6):

For me a tidier solution was to use Remove-SmbMapping and New-SmbMapping instead. This code works as expected:

```
Function New-MappedDrive ([Char]$Letter, [string]$Path){
    If (-not (Test-Path -Path $Path)) {
        Write-Host "  Unable to map drive '"$Letter"' - Invalid path" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
    else{
        #Remove existing connections
        if ("$($Letter):" -in (Get-SmbMapping).LocalPath){Remove-SmbMapping -LocalPath $Letter":" -Force | Out-Null}

        New-SmbMapping -LocalPath $Letter":" -RemotePath $Path -Persistent $true | Out-Null
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks interessting. The help only showed my a possibility for the password in clear text. Is an option `-Credential` like in `New-PSDrive` available?

Answer (score 3):

Try this method.  I couldn't get this to work either using the below commands separately, but together it finally cleared the mappings properly.   I'm thinking it might be related to the 'Persist' parameter when mapping the drives (but this isn't supposed to matter when removing according to the MS documentation).   I used Try..Catch block (not the most elegant) but this method does complain about drive not present if you try to run it another time after drives are already removed otherwise.

```
try
{
$mappings_to_remove = Get-PSDrive L, I -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Remove-PSDrive $mappings_to_remove -PSProvider FileSystem -Scope Global -erroraction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
Remove-SMBMapping $mappings_to_remove -Force -erroraction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
}
catch
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous ways to mount shares in WinOS - leverage `Get-PSDrive`, `Get-SmbMapping`, `Get-SmbGlobalMapping`, `net use`, etc. to list existing shares. Make sure to run `powershell.exe` as an admin and run the removla command associated with how the mount was created. You don't need to touch the registry looking for `MountPoints2` - this is a hack.

### Removing Global SMB Share

```
Remove-SmbGlobalMapping K:
```

### Removing SMB Share

```
Remove-SmbMapping K:
```

### Removing PS Share

```
Remove-PSDrive K
```

### Net Use

```
net use K: /delete
```